# Intel IMSM firmware with added PCIe Controller

Tags: raid, intel, rst

I currently have a RAID 10 (6x 2TB) running in an Intel IMSM container ("fakeraid", firmware RAID) on Ubuntu 16.04 on an ASUS H170M-PLUS (Intel H170 chipset).

I'm using all 6 SATA ports on the MOBO and want to add a PCIe JBOD controller and add the disks on that to the IMSM container.

Is this a possibility? Will the Intel Rapid Storage firmware add disks from a different controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. However for anything being pretty decent (ZFS or Storage Spaces) you don't want any fake RAID. Go for simple HBA (LSI has ones for sure) passing disks AS IS.

Comment: In case of LSI HBAs to be able to pass disks AS IS be sure to flash the controllers with IT firmware (not the IR one).

Comment: I went with a separate mirror and used LVM to increase the storage pool for now (I found an old PCIe raid card and decided to use it). I'll probably end up looking into ZFS down the road (still planning my homelab), so I'll take a look at HBAs. On a related note, how is ZFS for stability and ease of use? I've been hearing about it for awhile, but haven't tried it yet. Thanks!